# visual studio desktop application for iphone/Android apps

Tags: iphone, android

i want to develop one desktop application using c# sql lite, this application i want to submit this app to Apple store in case of iphone/ likewise for Android. please let me know if it is feasible to do, if so please let me know the steps that need to be incorporated in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't do this directly.

You need third party compilers to run C# code on iPhone ([MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/)) or Android ([MonoDroid](http://monodroid.net/)).

Do keep in mind that, even if you use MonoTouch (or MonoDroid) you won't be using Windows Forms, WPF or any other Windows based GUI framework. You will be using different frameworks to support Apple and Google's platform capabilities. So if you were thinking to run existing C# applications on iPhone or Android, it won't be possible.

Comment: thanks Pablo, can you please suggests me any other tool, platform which can be used in order to create a apps for both iphone and android.

Comment: Hi user638904. I have already did. Check out MonoDroid and MonoTouch. You can use C# in combination with them to create APPs for both platforms.